# How to set the background image in asp.net mvc4

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html

At the head I removed the master page reference

```
@{
Layout = null
}
```

in my head css:

```
 html { 
         background-image:url('Images\BGP.jpg');
}
```

But nothing changed, can anybody give me some suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP URLs use forward slashes.

They're also relative to the calling file; you probably want a domain-relative path that starts with `/`.

Comment: @JuanMendes: Yes; that's what I meant to say.  Thanks